# Helm yaml keys from values.yaml

Tags: yaml, go-templates, kubernetes-helm

I want to make a yaml KEY (not the value) dynamically.

In my `values.yaml`

```
failoverip1: 0.0.0.0` (<- this is only a demo IP)
```

In my `templates/configmap.yaml` I have this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vip-configmap
data:
  {{- .Values.failoverip1 -}}: {{ .Release.Namespace -}}/{{- .Values.target -}}
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----> here should be an IP address from values.yaml
```

`{{ .Release.Namespace -}}/{{- .Values.target -}}` renders successfully.

But if I add `{{- .Values.failoverip1 -}}` to the key part, it renders nothing.
(Nothing means, the whole `data:` block, does not get rendered.

This is the error message when I run `helm install --name hetzner-failover .`

`Error: YAML parse error on hetzner-failover/templates/configmap-ip.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Is it not allowed to make a

- key dynamic?
- If not, how to drive around that?

Here is the repo I am talking of:

https://github.com/exocode/helm-charts/blob/master/hetzner-failover/templates/configmap-ip.yaml

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: But to answer your question: The template is just treated as standard text. Keys and values are not special, to the templating engine, so anything can be dynamic.

Comment: @Flimzy. So it should no problem to parse any text? I added now the error in the question: `Error: YAML parse error on hetzner-failover/templates/configmap-ip.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Comment: It's no problem for the templating engine to parse any text. Helm still expects you to produce valid YAML, though (that error says you are not doing so).

Comment: I found the solution: it was the leading `-` which truncated the intedation :-)  `{{ .Values.failoverip1 | indent 2 -}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be, that the leading `-` got cut.

So the correct way is to remove that minus:

**Before:**

```
{{- .Values.failoverip1 | indent 2 -}}
```

**After:**

```
{{ .Values.failoverip1 | indent 2 -}}
```

The yaml is now:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vip-configmap
data:
{{ .Values.failoverip1 | indent 2 -}}: {{ .Release.Namespace -}}/{{- .Values.target -}} # add your config map here. must map the base64 encoded IP in secrets.yaml
```

And the rendered result is:

```
kubectl get configmap -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  data:
    0.0.0.0: default/nginx# add your config map here. must map the base64 encoded
      IP in secrets.yaml
  kind: ConfigMap
```